# How to pattern match exception with type test in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a function in which I need to **pattern match** (not `try...with`) the **exception** with type test in the following snippet:

```
module Error =

    type Codes =
        | InvalidUser = 0
        | InvalidEmail = 1

    exception AppException of Codes

    let errorHandler (e: exn) =
        // This doesn't work
        match e with
        | :? AppException as err(code) ->
            code.ToString()
        | _ -> e.Message
```

The `errorHandler` is a generic function to catch `AppExeption` as well as other non-handled exceptions in the application.

How can I use pattern matching with **Type Test** and destructure/retrieve `code` as part of `AppException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, there's two changes I'd make here:

1. Change `Codes` from an enum into a DU
2. Drop the type test, since it's not necessary for F#-defined exceptions

It would probably look like this:

```
open System

module Error =

    type Codes =
        | InvalidUser
        | InvalidEmail

    exception AppException of Codes

    let errorHandler (e: exn) =
        match e with
        | AppException codes ->
            match codes with
            | InvalidUser -> "invalid users!"
            | InvalidEmail -> "invalid email!"
        | _ -> e.Message
```

Alternatively, if nested pattern matching offends you, you can flatten it in this case:

```
let errorHandler (e: exn) =
    match e with
    | AppException InvalidUser ->
        "invalid user!"
    | AppException InvalidEmail ->
        "invalid email"
    | _ -> e.Message
```

F#-defined exceptions are effective single-case discriminated unions that you can pattern match directly on. There's no type testing involved here.

If `Codes` must remain an enum you can still do the first code sample, but you'll need a catch-all case in the inner match expression because an enum is just an `int` under the covers.

```
let errorHandler (e: exn) =
    // This doesn't work
    match e with
    | AppException codes ->
        match codes with
        | Codes.InvalidUser -> "invalid users!"
        | Codes.InvalidEmail -> "invalid email!"
        | _ -> "something else?"
    | _ -> e.Message
```